# Check if object position and rotation are zero

Tags: python, transforms

I want to check if all object transforms are at zero with python. What I have so far is this:

```
 object = bpy.context.active_object

 if any(object.location) or any(object.rotation_euler):
    print(object.location)
    print(object.rotation_euler)
```

This statement `any(object.rotation_euler)` doesn't seem to work correctly as it returns true despite there being no rotation.

How do I change the statement to make it work?

Comment: If object has a non-zero location, the conditional evaluates to `True`, and the rotation of (0,0,0) will be printed. Also,this approach is very vulnerable to floating point errors. A tiny translation or rotation (resulting from say, +x and -x  rotations) may display as 0,  but not be, at high precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can try rounding the values to 2-3 decimal points when comparing with 0 to make sure you're not falling victim to floating point errors:

```
object = bpy.context.active_object

def nozeros( vec, decimal_points = 2 ):
    ''' Returns True if none of the elements in the provided vector vec
        equate to zero when rounded by the provided number of decimal_points
    '''

    return any( round( v, decimal_points ) for v in vec )

if nozeros(object.location) or nozeros(object.rotation_euler):
    print(object.location)
    print(object.rotation_euler)
```

If either the location or rotation of the active object is non-zero this will script print the values of both.

Comment: suggest reducing to `any(round(v, decimal_points)  for v in vec)`

Comment: @batFINGER Definitely more elegant, done